# How to store data to multiple collections with same ID in Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have data that I want to store in multiple collections and apply the best practices of Firebase Firestore. Here's a document:

```
 [
       "postID": documentID,
       "category": self.category,
       "title": self.postTitle,
       "description": self.postDescription,
       "date": self.postDate,
       "imageURL": self.postImageURL
 ]
```

My idea is to store the same document in multiple places by same ID so it's faster to retrieve. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
let documentID: String = db.collection("collectionName").document().documentID

let allPosts: DocumentReference = db.collection("allPosts").document(documentID)
let postsByDate: DocumentReference = db.collection("dates").document(self.postDate).collection(documentID)
let postsByCategory: DocumentReference = db.collection("category").document.(self.category).collection(documentID)
```

When I have generated documentID once for all, I don't want to `addDocument` but rather `setData` so that it doesn't nest the data with another ID but CollectionReference doesn't seem to have `setData`.

I even tried using `db.document("dates").setData()` but that throws an error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but dates has 1'
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/DocumentReference#setdata_) with your three existing DocumentReference objects and pass it the dictionary with the data to add to the collection.  You don't need to call other any methods on a CollectionReference other than what you're already doing.

```
let data = ... // your dictionary of data
allPosts.setData(data)
```

Comment: Yes, that shall work fine. But for other references, I'd want to nest the documents with, let's say, dates like `db.collection("dates").document(self.postDate).collection(documentID)` so that each date has multiple documents. Is that achievable and is the right way to do?

Comment: The right thing to do is whatever satisfies your queries.  There are as many ways to model your data as there are kinds of queries you might want to perform.  If a model doesn't satisfy your query, it's not a very good model.